# JOptionPane Input Dialog how to decide if the value is 2 or JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION

Tags: java, swing, parsing, input, joptionpane

i use the following Code to get an InputDialog:

```
String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select number",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
```

I also want that the User only uses IntegerValues between 0 and 100.
I handle this by the following code:

```
while(notAllowed){
    try{
        int t =Integer.parseInt(c);
        if(t==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            notAllowed=false;
            cancel=true;
        }
        if(t<=100 && t>0 &&notAllowed)
            notAllowed=false;
    }
    catch( Exception err)
    {}
    if(notAllowed)
        c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Only Numbers between 1 and 100 are allowed");
    }
```

Now if the uses types the number 2 its like clicking the Cancel Button because the Value of JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION is also 2.
So how can i find out if Cancel is clicked or the input Value is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOptionPane returns null if the user clicks on cancel. Otherwise the value will be returned.
I figured that out using this small example:

```
public class JOptionPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "test", "test-text");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

}
```